# How do I correctly inject a login service in a beforeEach for protractor e2e tests using chromedriver?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, protractor

The test currently looks like

> ```
> describe('if authenticated', function() {
>   beforeEach(function() {
>     var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
>     ptor.waitForAngular();
>     browser.executeAsyncScript(function() {
>       var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
>       var loginService = angular.injector(['ng', 'firebase', 'myApp.config', 'myApp.service.firebase', 'myApp.service.login']).get('loginService');
>       loginService.init();
>       loginService.login(browser.params.login.user, browser.params.login.password, callback);
>       callback(null, true);
>     });
>   });
>
>   it('should stay on account screen if authenticated', function() {
>     browser.get('/app/index.html#/account');
>
>     // expect(browser.window().hash()).toBe('/account');
>     expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/\/account/);
>   });
> });
> ```

There are two errors that I can't get around, either 'Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {}' or 'unknown error: angular is not defined', depending on the waitForAngular call.

How can I accomplish this so that the test passes?

**Edit:**

I also see 'UnknownError: javascript error: browser is not defined', if I run that test as part of the test suite (all other tests pass).

This is the only test that tries to inject the loginService in the beforeEach for an authenticated page.  Getting access to angular in the afterEach seems to work as expected.

**File** config/protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  // The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.HTTP_PORT || '8000'),

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
...
```

Comment: 'UnknownError: javascript error: browser is not defined': you need to add chrome to your config file [link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/example/chromeOnlyConf.js)
And 'Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {}':  selenium/webdriver-manager running?

Comment: thanks for trying to help - see the config file excerpt above - didn't want to do 'chrome only' - do i need to? - yes selenium/webdriver-manager was running - any other thoughts?

Comment: just discovered, there is an open issue about this [link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/49)
try to add "ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;" before running your first test. forgot: no, you dont need to configure 'chrome only', but if you dont use phantom.js (or similar tools) you will need to configure a browser (if i didn't missed anything ;o  )

Comment: had tried this before, but thought it was a solved issue - retrying just put me back into the 'angular is not defined' camp

Answer (score 1):

You can move the login to the onPrepare block of the config file.

```
onPrepare: function() {
    // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters
    // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
    // this until inside the onPrepare function.
     require('jasmine-reporters');
     browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
     browser.driver.get("https://xyz.com");
     browser.driver.findElement(by.id('loginPageUsername')).sendKeys('jdoe@email.com');
     browser.driver.findElement(by.id('loginPagePassword')).sendKeys('mypass');
     browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.login')).click();

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('functional_results/', true, true));
  }
```

,